# Beginner VBA: Learning Basic Dim Format

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA and do not understand enough about Dim to even find the error.

1. The following code should create an object variable that can store information about a Workbook object. What is wrong with the following code? Correct the error(s).

```
Dim wkbInventory as Workbook     
wkbInventory  =   Application.Workbooks(“myWorkbook.xlsm”)
```

New to VBA and do not really understand/know enough about Dim to fix this.

Answer (score 2):

First, the `“curly quotes”` will not work... you need the `"normal ones"`.

Secondly, you need to use `Set` - as a `Workbook` is an `Object` variable.

```
Dim wkbInventory as Workbook
Set wkbInventory = Application.Workbooks("myWorkbook.xlsm")
```

That also assumes the workbook is already open, if it is not, then you need to do it like this instead:

```
Dim wkbInventory as Workbook
Set wkbInventory = Workbooks.Open("C:\Test\myWorkbook.xlsm")
```

or like this:

```
Dim wkbInventory as Workbook
Set wkbInventory = Workbooks.Add("C:\Test\myWorkbook.xlsm")
```

<sub>Note: A lot of times, normal quotes will turn into curly quotes if you are copy/pasting from a website that does not format things properly, or you are copy/pasting from something like a Word document. Try to pay attention to that.</sub>

Comment: does  Dim wkbInventory As Workbook
Set wkbInventory = Application.Workbooks.Item("Book1.xlsm") work the same or no? Assuming the workbook is open

Comment: Yes, that will work too, as `Item` is just the default for `Workbooks` - There's just no need for it. Keep in mind if the workbook has not been saved yet, then it will not have an extension, so you would use: `Set wkbInventory = Workbooks.Item("Book1")` or `Set wkbInventory = Workbooks("Book1")`

Comment: In BASIC, from 1964, `Let` assigned values to variables. When visual BASICs appeared they used `set` to assign a object to a variable. Variables are data but objects are code (that may return data). As compilers can tell what a=5 mean Let is depreciated in most BASICs and removed in the newest.

Comment: `set` has also been removed in newest BASICs. The compiler can tell if you're assigning an object - a collection of function calls.